# Android ListView not appearing

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-tabhost

My listview doesnt seem to show on screen.

I'm using a tabhost and put a list in a frame but for some reason it's not working.

I'm sure my code seems right so am unsure what's wrong here..

Help please!

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="List"
            android:id="@+id/listtext"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ListView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Tab 1 Code:

```
public class WorkoutDay1 extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.workoutlist_main);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Chest Press",
                "Shoulder Press",
                "Arm Extension",
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

/*                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition     = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);*/

                // Show Alert
                if(position == 0) {
                    //code specific to first list item
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), workout.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                }

                if(position == 1) {
                    //code specific to 2nd list item
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Coming Soon.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

                if(position == 2) {
                    //code specific to 2nd list item
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Coming Soon." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

            }

        });




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You hvnt posted your complete code but I am just guessing that you might not have called `notifyDataSetChanged()` after assigning data to your list..

Comment: Ive updated my code, not too sure where to put what you said.

Comment: Add it after the line listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I guess its your first application using list.. You have to call it on adapter.. write adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Always remember to call notifyDataSetChanged() whenever you make changes to the list.. In your case in hand, you need to separate up the layouts.. One xml will be there only to define the tabs.. The other will be to define the List View.. And yet another one for the each list view item.. refer to the following tutorial for understanding how to include list inside the TAB..  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/ .. You may play around with your existing code after going through this tutorial..

Comment: Before making any changes, try once changing the height attribute of the listview too.. I can see you have used android:layout_height="0dp" .. Instead try android:layout_height="match_parent" once.

Comment: In design view this is whats happening: http://puu.sh/fJdaz/50f7076580.jpg 
Obviously the list should be in the frame and not appearing as the tab.

Comment: So change your layouts.. Possibly use the tutorial I have posted in one of my comments.. Your tabs itself are not showing up.. Definitely some prob with the tabhost layout.. (Possibly remove list view from there)

Comment: Okay i will give it a go.

Comment: Attempting to follow that tutorial, dont really want to populate using JSON so having bit of trouble at the moment.